# printk() messages not appearing in console

Tags: linux, kernel-module, printk

So I'm trying to learn to write Linux modules and right now I'm experimenting with a basic "Hello World" module:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
MODULE_LICENSE("Dual BSD/GPL");

static int hello_init(void){

    printk(KERN_ALERT "Hello, world.\n");
    return 0;
}

static void hello_exit(void){

    printk(KERN_ALERT "goodbye.\n");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

And I've finally gotten this module to work! When I add with insmod it prints "hello" to kernel.log and when I remove it with remmod it prints "goodbye" to kernel.log.

My trouble is that I decided I want to try and get the output to also print to the console. From what I understand about printk(), is that in order for messages to show up in the console, the console must be set to the appropriate message level in /proc/sys/kernel/printk. (This is all according to https://elinux.org/Debugging_by_printing). My console is set to level 4.

cat  /proc/sys/kernel/printk:

```
4       4       1       7
```

Since KERN_ALERT is level 2 and my console is set to print out level 4 and below messages, why are the printk messages not appearing on my console? When I run dmesg I can see the messages are clearly in the buffer, but never go to the console. It's not I really need them to print to the console, but I really want to understand how this all works.

Comment: Try `# tail -f /var/log/messages`

Comment: @PeterL. Hmm, I dont have a /var/log/messages file, and I'm not really concerned about printing to the console for practical reasons, but rather I want to better understand the linux system and the reasons why kernel messages are not appearing in my console. I can see the messages appear in my kernel.log file and I can see them when I run dmesg, but I think I'm misunderstanding some fundamental concept of what it means for kernel messages to "print to the console". I've run "dmesg -E" to enable console messages, but still I'm not seeing them on my my console

Comment: Show _/proc/cmdline_.

Comment: @0andriy here's my /proc/cmdline contents: ```BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-59-generic root=UUID=15ff438c-dddc-4f38-bf94-d016fc7b4fa0 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7```

Comment: You have `quiet` parameter. Have you tried to drop it?

Comment: @0andriy I removed quiet, ran ```grub-update``` and rebooted, but unfortunately kernel messages are still not appearing in xconsole or tty1

Comment: Okay, if you add `console=tty0` to the command line, does it help?

Comment: Same problem here, is there a solution please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope i can answer to your question. I also faced same issue and tried my level best to print kernel message to console, but nothing works. Then I started searching for the reason...

The reason is,  If klogd is not running, the message won’t reach user space unless you read /proc/kmsg. Reference: [oreilly](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/linux-device-drivers/0596000081/ch04.html) or /dev/kmsg. klogd reads kernel log messages and helps process and send those messages to the appropriate files, sockets or users. since absence of daemon, it won't send to standard output. Unless you read the message from ring buffer or buffer overflow, it will remains.